# System Design: Global Caching and consistency

Tags: caching, architecture, system-design

Lets take an example of Twitter. There is a huge cache which gets updated frequently. For example: if person Foo tweets and it has followers all across the globe. Ideally all the caches across all PoP needs to get updated. i.e. they should remain in sync

How does replication across datacenter (PoP) work for realtime caches ? 
What tools/technologies are preferred ?
What are potential issues here in this system design ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure there is a right/wrong answer to this, but here's my two pennies' worth of it.

I would tackle the problem from a slightly different angle: when a user posts something, that something goes in a distributed storage (not necessarily a cache) that is already redundant across multiple geographies. I would also presume that, in the interest of performance, these nodes are eventually consistent.

Now the caching. I would not design a system that takes care of synchronising all the caches each time someone does something. I would rather implement caching at the service level. Imagine a small service residing in a geographically distributed cluster. Each time a user tries to fetch data, the service checks its local cache - if it is a miss, it reads the tweets from the storage and puts a portion of them in a cache (subject to eviction policies). All subsequent accesses, if any, would be cached at a local level.

In terms of design precautions:

- Carefully consider the DC / AZ topology in order to ensure sufficient bandwidth and low latency
- Cache at the local level in order to avoid useless network trips
- Cache updates don't happen from the centre to the periphery; cache is created when a cache miss happens
- I am stating the obvious here, implement the right eviction policies in order to keep only the right objects in cache
- The only message that should go from the centre to the periphery is a cache flush broadcast (tell all the nodes to get rid of their cache)

I am certainly missing many other things here, but hopefully this is good food for thought.

Comment: This sounds good for write and then read kind of system. if the system needs atomicity. for example: banking transaction. eventually consistent persistence across DCs won't work here. How do you think that should be handled ?

Comment: You might want to ask that as a separate question. Finance is a different kettle of fish altogether. There a good reason that traditional RDMS with their ACID compliance and transaction management are heavily used by the industry. Much of the design of these technologies was driven by banking requirements.